# Word 2007, Adding Page Numbers to Landscape, 5.5 by 8.5 Booklet Style Document

Tags: formatting, microsoft-word-2007, layout, landscape

I am publishing a 5.5 by 8.5 booklet.  I created this document in Word 2007 and will be converting it to PDF.  It looks good as is, but I can't seem to figure out how to add page numbers automatically to this document.

In general, I know how to add page numbers using footers, etc, but this application is a bit different:  I have two pages (5.5 by 8.5) on one landscape 8.5 by 11 page.

I guess I could manually add page numbers, but then getting the formatting perfect will be tough.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some great ideas from quack quixote, I tried some other stuff and found an answer to this question.  I converted the Word document to PDF and, then using Illustrator, opened the document and formatted it the way I needed to and added page numbers.  Then I can save back into a PDF.  It worked nicely, and I gained additional formatting flexibility.

Comment: I am glad you found a solution, but for future documents you may want to consider a different setup. Your page layout would be for landscape letter pages and on the page setup margins tab, select Book fold (you'll see a preview to show how the pages will be portrait). Page numbers can be inserted as typical. In the case where you want a page's content in landscape, you could rotate the content on a portrait page, or insert section breaks before and after the page, deselect Same as Previous on the page and the page following, and insert the page number in a rotated text box.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't done this since Word '97 so I can't provide a step-by-step procedure, but either method should be quite achievable:

1. You could manually add page numbers in a page footer; formatting won't be overly difficult that way.  Use centered tabstops in the footer prototype to make numbering easier.
2. Or, you can revert to a standard document designed for portrait 8.5"x11" pages (again, page numbers in the footer, but automatic numbering will suffice).

   When you go to print the document, set your print options to print 2 pages per page (one-sided) or 2 pages per side (double-sided).  This should handle the rotating and placing 2-pages-in-landscape for you.  Print that way to a PDF printer to get a nice PDF pre-formatted just the way you want it.

Comment: Unfortunately, Word 2007 is too "smart."  Really, it's amazingly stupid, but Microsoft thinks it's smart...  I cannot format each individual footer.  The best I can do is format odds and evens differently.  There are, in addition, no good page number formats that would work either...  Your second suggestion is a good one, but, unfortunately for me, I formatted this darn thing using the landscape, two-column method.  When I change it back to one column, vertical orientation, all my formatting is lost, i.e., pictures, spacial organization.

Comment: @nico: you may find it easier to "revert" to Portrait formatting by opening a new document, then copy-and-pasting from the Landscape version into the Portrait version.  this should keep more of your internal formatting, but converting will require some work. playing with margins and font sizes may help maintain the formatting a bit better.  still, converting will take some work.  maybe someone else can tell you a way to make Option #1 work for you.

Comment: @quack quixote:  Thanks for the suggestion.  It's looking like you might be right.  But this will take a while and some of the graphics I used are sized (including resolution, etc) for the smaller page.  You would think that since Word allows for multiple columns, it would have an option for numbering these columns, as if they were actual pages!?  Anyway, we'll see.......  Thanks!

Comment: @nico: i have a suspicion you can add a formula in the footer that calculates your page number (eg option 1).  but it's solidly beyond me at the moment.  sorry i can't be more help.

Comment: @quixote: That's OK.  You might be right and I will look into that.  Thanks again.

Comment: @quack quixote:  You have any hints on this (looking for #)? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49576/etiquette-question-is-there-a-way-to-contact-moderators-for-specific-reputation